# What is the correct method for determining 'is_front_page' when using filters such as 'pre_get_posts' and 'posts_where'?

Tags: conditional-tags, frontpage

On my site several filters should be applied if the user is viewing the static home page.  My understanding is that [`is_front_page()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) should determine if that is indeed the case.

However, whenever I use the function I find that sometimes it returns `true` (e.g. `posts_orderby`) but mostly it returns `false` (e.g. `pre_get_posts`, `posts_fields`, `posts_join` and `posts_where`).  Regardless of the result though, I always recieve the following notice -

> Trying to get property of non-object in {my_path}\wp-includes\query.php on line 4373

The method containing the offending line is `WP_Query::is_front_page()` -

```
public function is_front_page() {
    // most likely case
    if ( 'posts' == get_option( 'show_on_front') && $this->is_home() )
        return true;
    /** The offending line */ elseif ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front') && get_option( 'page_on_front' ) && $this->is_page( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

To combat this issue I have created my own function, as below, but it seems "dirty" to have had to do so.  So my question is thus - is there a better way to do this?

```
function fgw_is_front_page($q){

    if(!is_a($q, 'WP_Query'))
        return false;

    return (get_option('show_on_front') == 'page' && get_option('page_on_front') && $q->get('page_id') == get_option('page_on_front'));

}
```

---

## Edit

Afer further investigation it seems that the offending line is actually 4369 (wp-includes/querey.php) - `$page_obj = $this->get_queried_object();`

`$page_obj` is being returned as `null`, meaning that check for `$q->is_front_page()` fails.  This seems wrong, and unless anyone is able to explain how this could in any way be expected behaviour I'll look at opening a ticket on Trac.

---

## Update

I have now amended the above function.  Making use of the second argument passed to all of the filters that I am using (the WP_Query instance), as mentioned by **@birgire**, has allowed me to do away with the global.

However, taking the below example, I am still receiving the aformentioned notice (and result of `false`) when checking `$q->is_front_page()` -

```
add_filter('posts_fields','fgw_index_posts_fields', 10, 2);
function fgw_index_posts_fields($fields, $q){
    
    global $wpdb;

    if(!is_admin() && is_main_query() && (is_home() || $q->is_front_page($q)))
        $fields.= $wpdb->prepare(', %1$s.name as category_name', $wpdb->terms);
    
    return $fields;
    
}
```

Replacing `$q->is_front_page()` with `fgw_is_front_page($q)` works, but again it feels dirty to have to use a custom solution when seemingly there is one that already exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the `posts_orderby`, `posts_where`, `posts_join` and `posts_clauses` hooks, the current `\WP_Query` object is available through the *second* input argument.

These are the relevant parts from the `\WP_Query` class:

```
$orderby = apply_filters_ref_array( 'posts_orderby', array( $orderby, &$this ) );
$where   = apply_filters_ref_array( 'posts_where', array( $where, &$this ) );
$join    = apply_filters_ref_array( 'posts_join', array( $join, &$this ) );
$clauses = (array) apply_filters_ref_array( 'posts_clauses', array( compact( $pieces ), &$this ) );
```

all using the [`apply_filters_ref_array`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters_ref_array) function and `&$this` is the current `\WP_Query` instance. The Codex says the following about this function:

> This function is identical to `apply_filters`, but the arguments passed
>   to the functions hooked to $tag are supplied using an array.

You can access the second argument with for example:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', function( $where, \WP_Query $q )
{
    if( $q->is_front_page() ) <-- This method won't work here with a static front-page!!!
    {
        // ...
    }
}, 10, 2 );
```

so you don't have to rely on the global `$wp_query` object.

After tracing this inside `WP_Query`, we've found the reason why calling the  `is_front_page()` method doesn't work inside these filter callbacks. There problem lies within the `is_page()` method that tries to use the `get_queried_object()` method that still hasn't got an object to return.

The `is_home()` method works on the other hand, and it isn't calling  the `is_page()` method.

### Update:

There seems to be at least two Trac tickets, [#27015](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27015) and [#21790](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21790), that related to this problem.

In #27015 there's a suggested [patch](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/27015/27015.3.patch) by @mattonomics, that modifies the `queried_object` object within the `parse_query()` method.

So why not try these modifications in our case, but through the `parse_query` hook instead:

```
/**
 * A workaround for the is_front_page() check inside pre_get_posts and later hooks.
 *
 * Based on the patch from @mattonomics in #27015
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188320/26350
 */

add_action( 'parse_query', function( $q )
{
    if( is_null( $q->queried_object ) && $q->get( 'page_id' ) )
    {
        $q->queried_object    = get_post( $q->get( 'page_id' ) );
        $q->queried_object_id = (int) $q->get( 'page_id' );
    }
} );
```

We should be able to add further changes this way, from that patch.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've now added the second argument (kind of embarrased I missed that!), meaning I can do away with the global in my `fgw_is_front_page()` function.  However, trying to use `$q->is_front_page()`, as in your example, still results in the notice posted in my question (this time for all of my filters though) and the result of `false`.

Comment: Try to use `$q` as much you can instead of the global `$wp_query`, so try for example: `if( ! is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && ( $q->is_home() || $q->is_front_page() ) )` in your code example.

Comment: But `$q->is_front_page()` doesn't work, it always returns a notice and `false`, no matter what page I am on. And for using `$q` against the other examples, presumably that is desirable because the core functions `is_home()`, etc. use the global `$wp_query`, rather than it being my code that uses an undesirable global?

Comment: I can confirm that I get these errors, once I put up a static page. It looks like it's too early to call the `is_page()` method inside that filter callback. This check is inside the `is_front_page()` method but not `is_home()` method. The `is_page()` method contains   the `get_queried_object()` method, that's empty in your case for the first time at least. I guess that's expected, before we have even fetched it from the database @DavidGard ps: oh I see you've come to the same conclusion after reading your updated answer ;-)

Comment: Ha ha, yep, been playing around for ages.  I can see now why it's not working, but surly a valid case for checking is_front_page() is when manipulating the query? I'm strongly leaning towards opening a ticket on Trac, with the suggestion that they use code similar to my solution, as that should work in all instances.

Comment: Although I've marked this as the answer because it does address my initial query and should make my site more efficient.

Comment: so currently it looks like your `fgw_is_front_page()` is the way to go here ;-) I just searched around and it looks like tickets [#21790](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21790) and [#27015](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27015) addresses similar problem @DavidGard

Comment: Cool, I'll just add my thoughts to hose then.

Comment: I updated the answer with an idea from the suggested patch, but using the `parse_query` filter instead. @DavidGard

Comment: Good find, that does indeed work. Hopefully the WP powers-that-be will listen and make the minor adjustments necessary to include this functionality.

Answer (score 4):

instead of

`$query->is_front_page()`

try using

`$query->get('page_id') == get_option('page_on_front')`

(in context:)

```
function custom_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( $query->get('page_id') == get_option('page_on_front') ) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts');
```

This solution is from here:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21790#comment:11