# Weird problem with pre_get_posts and $query->is_page()

Tags: pre-get-posts, wp-redirect

The following bit of code was used in my fictitious plugin to redirect the non-logged-in users from page `173` (ID) to `sample-page` (slug). The code's working well. But just today, I figured out that the code is causing Notices <del>in Firefox</del>.

The issue happened when I tried setting a Static Page as the front page from Settings » Reading.

> **Notice:** Trying to get property of non-object in
> `/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php` on line 3760
> **Notice:** Trying to get property of non-object in
> `/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php` on line 3762
> **Notice:** Trying to get property of non-object in
> `/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php` on line 3764

With several inspection, I figured out that, the following bit of code is causing the issue. And to be specific the issue is with the `is_page(173)`.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query) {
  if( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() && ! is_user_logged_in() && $query->is_page(173) ) {
    wp_redirect(home_url('/sample-page'));
    exit();
  }
});
```

I tried changing from `$query->is_page(173)` to `is_page(173)` - the result is same.

To test in a blank installation, I tried disabling all the plugins and set the default theme TwentySixteen, and re-installed WordPress to get a fresh install. I put the following code in TwentySixteen's `functions.php`, and with DEBUG *on*, [here's what I got](http://dev.nanodesignsbd.com/). (The notice is under the black area of header, just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to see 'em) <del>You can check the redirection is working from [this page](http://dev.nanodesignsbd.com/level-2/) (`173`) to [this page](http://dev.nanodesignsbd.com/sample-page/) without any notice.</del>

What's the problem with my code?

Comment: What context is your hook being called from? Might be worth simplifying it for the sake of troubleshooting by creating a named function instead of a closure.

Comment: @ChrisCox I'm afraid can't get you. I explained my context - redirecting non-logged-in users from one page to another. Anyway, I named it now on the live link.

Comment: By context, I mean is it in the global scope or in a class method?

Comment: If you look at the lines it calls out in source, it's trying to read some properties from what it assumes is a page object, but in this case it's not. I'll guess that you can't check if it's a specific page *before* the query is run if it is in fact not a page at all. If you think about it, it's strange that it would work at all considering you're checking what it is *pre* getting the object.

Comment: [This is related](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/188317/26350)

Comment: @birgire Good call. I [tried with this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21790#comment:11), but even using `$query->get('page_id')` isn't producing any page ID. So I can't dictate in which page I'm in. So I can't redirect. Need not to mention, `$query->get('page_id') == 173` isn't working.

Comment: I couldn't figure out why it's not working, but I would try to do it with [template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect)

Comment: `pre_get_posts` isn't an appropriate filter to do this, like @Zex2911 says use the `template_redirect` filter instead

Answer (score 1):

`pre_get_posts` is innapropriate for this use, instead you should use the `template_redirect` filter, e.g.

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', funnction() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 123 ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url( '/sample-page' ) );
        exit;
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn off debug mode and it will be gone, at least worked for me. 
I know it's an old post but just want to help people with the same issue.